# How to auto mount / permanently mount external devices on NixOS

Tags: usb, ntfs, automounting, nixos

I have a USB stick and an NTFS hard drive partition that I'd want to use in NixOS. On some other distribution, I'd mount it using `ntfs-3g` in `/mnt`. But on NixOS, the directory doesn't exist; I suppose NixOS has some other canonical way and/or place of doing that.

In NixOS, how should one set up automounting of external partitions, preferably using `configuration.nix`?

Comment: open `nautilus` if you have `services.xserver.desktopManager.gnome3.enable = true;` in your `configuration.nix` and you'll see the drive and it'll get mounted at `/run/media/$USER/<drive name>`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, I costumarily use `bashmount` or `udisksctl` to mount USB sticks. They will be mounted in `/run/media/$(user name)/$(drive label or UUID)`.

But if you are talking about an internal harddisk or partition in a local harddrive, the simplest way is:

1. Create a directory of your preference, as /mnt/windows-partition
2. Mount the desired partition, say /dev/sdn5, in that directory:

> $ `mount /dev/sdn5 /mnt/windows-partition`

3. Run **nixos-generate-config**. It will update */etc/nixos/hardware-configuration.nix* to match the new partition configuration (and *configuration.nix* stays untouched, unless you use the **--force** option).
4. And, finally, a `nixos-rebuild switch`!

Comment: So regarding the omission of a `/mnt` directory, the answer seems to be "make your own or mount it wherever you like".

Comment: What is the purpose of step 3? Does this make the mount permanent?

Comment: Yep! That step is to register /mnt/windows-partition in the (machine-generated) file hardware-configuration.nix.

That way, it will be mounted next boot (after a nixos-rebuild, of course).

Comment: @AndersonTorres I followed these steps to permanently add a USB drive, but now that drive is mounted as `/dev/sda` whenever I boot the system. This is messing with NixOS, because it isn't the boot disk. The generated hardware config file refers to the disk as `device = "/dev/disk/by-uuid/<UUID>";`.
How do I change the configuration file to make sure my boot disk is `/dev/sda`?

Comment: @HiDefender I am afraid I am not understanding you here. As far as I remember, by default Nixpkgs uses UUIDs in its hardware configuration. It merely ignores `/dev/sd*`.

If I am understanding it correctly, you need to work with udev rules in order to make those symlinks. I can't help here, however.

https://discourse.nixos.org/t/how-to-create-files-in-the-etc-udev-rules-d-directory/

Answer (score 7):

I personally use [udisks](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/udisks/) for that. That means, if i want to mount an USB stick, i just have to plug it in and run:

```
$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdc
```

I aliased `udisksctl mount -b` to `udm` to make it even shorter. The device is then mounted in `/run/media/$USER/$DEVICE_LABEL` and accessible for you.

I think, some tools (e.g. [nautilus](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Nautilus) and [ldm](https://github.com/LemonBoy/ldm)) can do that automatically for you.

**EDIT**: [ah, i just found out that udisks can also automount devices.](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/udiskie)

Answer (score 1):

### Directly modifying `hardware-configuration.nix` file

---

To achieve the same results as mentioned in other answers, you can as well add another `fileSystems` config entry in `hardware-configuration.nix`:

```json
{
  ...

  fileSystems."${mount_location}" = {
    device = "/dev/${device}";
    fsType = "${filesystem_extension}";
  };

  ...
}
```

###### NOTES:

To get filesystem extension information about a particular partition run:

```bash
df -T | grep /dev/${device}
```

Example configuration for `/dev/sda1` device, having `ext4` file system extension, that is to be mounted at `/mnt/sda1` location:

```json
{
  ...

  fileSystems."/mnt/sda1" = {
    device = "/dev/sda1";
    fsType = "ext4";
  };

  ...
}
```

I think that such a solution is more unique, as the device name would not be overwritten by NixOS specific namespaces as in `nixos-generate-config`'s solution.