# How to mount internal drives as a normal user in NixOS?

Tags: mount, non-root-user, nixos, sata

In for example Thunar I can just click on an external USB drive to mount it under /run/media/$USER/[something]. The fact that the mount point is created dynamically is a great side effect. But for any drives which are on the SATA bus I'm told

> mount: only root can do that

or

> Not authorized to perform operation.

How do I configure internal drives to work like USB drives in this respect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround for mounting devices as a user.
A static line in `/etc/fstab` permits to `mount`/`umount` without being root :

```
/dev/sdc1 /mnt/sdc1 auto defaults,user,rw,utf8,noauto,umask=000 0 2
```

If `/dev/sdc1` device & `/mnt/sdc1` directory both exist, running either `mount /dev/sdc1` or `mount /mnt/sdc1` will mount the device on the directory.

Note that this workaround is valid for any GNU/Linux distribution.

Adding the following to the `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` will generate the above `/etc/fstab`-line for NixOS :

```
  fileSystems."/mnt/sdc1" = {
    device = "/dev/sdc1";
    fsType = "auto";
    options = [ "defaults" "user" "rw" "utf8" "noauto" "umask=000" ];
  };
```

Comment: One caveat to this is that the mount directory (`/mnt/sdc1` in this case) needs to be owned by the user in question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can mount internal devices as a normal user in Linux.

I had a similar problem, wanting to make an internal disk available to a normal user in NixOS. 
The answer [How to auto mount / permanently mount external devices on NixOS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213137/how-to-auto-mount-permanently-mount-external-devices-on-nixos) explains how to do auto mounting by mounting manually as a superuser, and running `nixos-generate-config` and `nixos-rebuild switch`.

Then using `chown user:group /my-mount-point` I was able to permanently configure the disk to be available to my user. 
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't succeed for me. It still asked for root password at login to mount.
But building on it, changing the options to the ones I had working in my manjaro system made it work.
Added this to my `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` file:

```
  fileSystems."/mnt/DataDisk" = {
    device = "/dev/disk/by-label/DataDisk";
    fsType = "auto";
    options = [ "nosuid" "nodev" "nofail" "x-gvfs-show"];
  };
```

`device = "/dev/disk/by-label/DataDisk"` finds the disk with the label `DataDisk`
`fileSystems."/mnt/DataDisk"` will create the folders `/mnt` & `/mnt/DataDisk` if they don't exist and mount it there

Then ran `sudo nixos-rebuild switch`

Comment: For me it did not actually create the `/mnt/DataDisk` folder. Did it for you?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner If I recall correctly, it created the `mnt` and the `DataDisk` directories by itself in my case